# Find the length of the intersection of two lists including duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 2 `Lists`.  The first one includes all the numbers from 1 to 10.

```
listA={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

The second includes random numbers, like this:

```
listB={2,10,2,5,7,15,1000,7,25,600}
```

I want to find an algorithm that will take any number of the second list `listB` and compare it to all numbers in `listA`. If the number in `listB` is equal to a number in `listA`, I"ll get 1 as a result. If not it will be 0. As a final result I would like to sum all equal numbers.

Here, for example we have the result 6 because we can find 2 (twice), 7 (twice), 5 and 10 in the two lists. I need a general way because my lists includes data of 10,000 numbers.

Comment: This is ambiguous, e.g., if a number in list 1 is in list 2 twice, does it count twice? And is it a count you're after, or a total of the actual numbers, and if the latter, total of what (matching numbers from both lists, just the matches from one list, ....)?

Comment: Further, do you just want to check for equality in corresponding positions? A full example with unsorted lists and duplicate numbers would really help.

Comment: To count all occurrences you can simply use : `Total @ Table[Count[l2, l1[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@l2}]`

Comment: @mgamer: That will overcount if l2 has elements that are repeated in l1...

Comment: @ciao: It´s not a bug, it´s a feature. I did this according to your first comment on this question and counted all occurrences.

Comment: Now that you've clarified the question, you'll find the following *much* faster on large lists than what's here right now (if question is taken off hold, I'll post as an answer). Try it, e.g., with say `listA=Range@100000; listB= RandomInteger[1000000, 10^6];` - it s/b orders of magnitude faster. 

`(Tr[Tally[#1~Join~#2][[;; Length@#1, 2]]] - Length[#1]) &[listA, listB]`

Answer (score 3):

This should be *much* more efficient for anything beyond small lists:

```
(Tr[Tally[#1~Join~#2][[;; Length@#1, 2]]] - Length[#1]) &[listA, listB]
```

Comment: What is it doing, and why is it so much faster?

Comment: +1 for superior general solution. I'm very surprised, that `Tally` is so fast.

Comment: @JasonB `Tally` gives the number of occurrences of the elements of the combined lists `A` and `B` but preserves the order in which the elements appear. Therefore the first `Length@listA` elements of `Tally[listA~Join~listB]` will give how many times the elements of `listB` appear in `listA` **plus one**. This hinges on the fact that all elements of `listA` must be distinct, but is otherwise more general than my solution, which demands `listA === Range@Length@listA`

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers seem to have been addressing a rather different (or much more generalized) sort of problem, because as I see this now, we have the following problem statement:

```
len = 10; (* let's have 10 to be specific, but this is an arbitrary positive integer *)
max = 10^3; (* maximum value of numbers in listB *)
listA = Range[len];
listB = RandomInteger[{1, max}, len];
```

Then *of course* a member of `listB` is a member of `listA` if it is less than (or equal to) `len`. So to get the matching numbers we do:

```
Pick[listB, # <= len &/@ listB]
(* {2, 10, 2, 5, 7, 7} *)
```

And to get the count of that, simply

```
Length@%
(* 6 *)
```

This is slower than @ciao's answer. However, this is almost 2 orders of magnitude faster:

```
Pick[listB, Sign[listB - len - 1], -1]
```

And this one is a tiny bit slower, but slightly more general (handles negative integers properly):

```
Pick[listB, Quotient[listB, len, 1], 0]
```

Here are the timings for the solutions:

```
len = 1000000;
max = 10000000;
listA = Range[len];
listB = RandomInteger[{1, max}, len];
(Tr[Tally[#1~Join~#2][[;; Length@#1, 2]]] - Length[#1]) &[listA, 
   listB] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Pick[listB, # <= len & /@ listB] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Pick[listB, Sign[listB - len - 1], -1] // AbsoluteTiming // First
Pick[listB, Quotient[listB, len, 1], 0] // AbsoluteTiming // First

0.556392 (* ciao *)
0.803501 (* boolean comparison *)
0.0136436 (* Sign *)
0.0171063 (* Quotient *)
```

Be aware, that while my solution is easily adaptable to the variations of the problem, as stated right now, if `listA` is also to have random numbers, as originally suggested, ciao's way is probably the fastest (and IMO, really elegant).

Comment: +1 on your interpretation of question and solution - if that *is* what OP means (a whole list, not a count, and listA always a monotonic range), doing something with `Pick` et al. will be quite quick.

Comment: @ciao *"A whole list, not a count"* - sure I omitted the `// Length` in the timings, but that's a trivial part, right? Wondering, if something smart could be done with `Ordering` and friends.

Comment: @Not sure the `Ordering` tricks would be so fast here - I considered but rejected offhand. I think, though, that `Tr@Unitize@Clip[listB, {1, len}, {0, 0}]` could be quick - but away from machine so can't test right now.

Comment: @ciao Yes, quite. 8-9ms averaged over 100 runs on the same machine. I was thinking of this approach, but overlooked the extra arguments of `Clip` that would make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the question has been restated, you can use a shortened version of the answer suggested by mgamer,

```
B = {2, 10, 2, 5, 7, 15, 1000, 7, 25, 600};
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Count[B, #] & /@ A // Total
(* 6 *)
```

Or you could use `MemberQ` and `Boole`,

```
Boole@MemberQ[A, #] & /@ B // Total
(* 6 *)
```

Or `Select`, `MemberQ`, and `Length`

```
Select[B, MemberQ[A, #] &] // Length
(* 6 *)
```

If speed is an issue, and the `B` list is very large, then the `Boole` method is slightly faster, and the `Select` method is by far the slowest.

```
SeedRandom[28];
A = Range[100];
B = RandomInteger[10000, 10^6];
Count[B, #] & /@ A // Total // AbsoluteTiming
Boole@MemberQ[A, #] & /@ B // Total // AbsoluteTiming
Select[B, MemberQ[A, #] &] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.113349, 10012} *)
(* {0.135395, 10012} *)
(* {4.06878, 10012} *)
```

If the `A` list gets larger, then the difference between the `Count` and `Boole` methods is minimal, but `Select` is **much** worse,

```
SeedRandom[28];
A = Range[1000];
B = RandomInteger[10000, 10^6];
Count[B, #] & /@ A // Total // AbsoluteTiming
Boole@MemberQ[A, #] & /@ B // Total // AbsoluteTiming
Select[B, MemberQ[A, #] &] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.896079, 100334} *)
(* {0.865092, 100334} *)
(* {25.8521, 100334} *)
```

Comment: Good answer. What is this `@*` syntax called? Seems to be handy... is it new in 10?

Comment: @TheoTiger, it is short for `Composition`, so in this case it saves me from having to type `Boole[SameQ[#]]&` - I believe the shorthand is new in 10.0

Comment: Thanks! Just looked it up, the infix is indeed new in 10. I always did something like `Boole@SameQ@##&`, but this is much nicer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess there is also a possibility to get a Table output of all equal numbers in both tables. How can I do it?

Comment: `Select[B, MemberQ[A, #] &]` returns `{2, 10, 2, 5, 7, 7}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the exact aim is. In the following it is assumed:

- 2 random samples from a range of integers (distinct elements) of equal length
- the aim is to determine size of intersection:

  f[n_, s_] := 
   Module[{a = RandomSample[Range[n], s], b = RandomSample[Range[n], s],
      j, u, c, r},
    c = Intersection[a, b];
    r = # -> Style[#, Bold, Red] & /@ c;
    {a /. r, b /. r, Length@c}]

Much of above is just *window dressing*.

Examples:

```
Grid[Table[f[10, 5], {5}]]
```

[image]

or

```
Grid[Table[f[20, 10], {5}]]
```

[image]